# How to add custom stylesheet to print pdf output?

Tags: 7, files

I have a view, displayed as table on single page.

HTML print view looks ok (I want border on every td), but it seems that I can't apply any styles to print pdf, I try to use HTML attributes and it seems, that only this is changing appearance of generated PDF.

Any chance to use CSS files to theme PDF output?

I am using Print module with additional PDF module (https://drupal.org/project/Print)

PDF library: tcpdf

**EDIT**

I just used old plain table attributes and it works inside PDF

Comment: Do you have problem with generating PDF files? If so, what module / library you use for generation? Or do you want to apply CSS to real pdf files you have on your server's HDD?

Comment: @Mołot question edited

Answer (score 1):

One of the benefits mentioned on the [PDF using mPDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/PDF_using_mPDF) project page is "Add custom Style Sheet to PDF". Here are some more quotes about this module (from the module's project page):

> ... used for Conversion of HTML pages to PDF documents using mPDF PHP Library. It allows you to generate a pdf document of any node.
>
> **Features**
>
> - PDF creation (www.example.com/node/nid/pdf) where nid is the node id of content to render.
> - PDF generation API is provided, the content developers can use this API to generate a PDF document.
> - By creating your own CSS file and/or the node.tpl.php template files, it is possible to change the look of the output page to suit your taste.
>
> **Benefits**
>
> - Document Properties
> - PDF Page settings
> - Watermark Image/Text
> - HTML Header & Footer
> - Password Protected PDF
> - Add custom Style Sheet to PDF
> - Enable/disable PDF generation for each Content type
> - Display/ hide any fields of Content type for PDF

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "print.css" file on your theme css folder. Print PDF will take it.

```
yourtheme/css/print.css
```